# Distance between quadratic forms

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, quadratic-forms

In notes here http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/gille/prenotes/lens.pdf on page $2$ a formulation of distance between two positive quadratic form $[q],[q']$ is given by 
$$d([q],[q'])=\frac{\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{q'(x)}{q(x)}}{\inf_{x\neq0}\frac{q'(x)}{q(x)}} $$ Is there a reference for this distance? what is the intuition behind this distance?

Are there any other distances?

Is it connected to distances here http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~subtypo3/gdz/pdf/PPN356556735_0104/PPN356556735_0104___LOG_0021.pdf?

Comment: I don't know whether this is *the* motivation for this definition, but if $q'$ and $q$ are closed, positive forms on Hilbert spaces $V,H$ and $V$ is densely and continuously embedded in $H$, then the numerator (resp., denominator) of your quotient is the largest (resp., smallest) eigenvalue of the operator $A$ on $H$ associated with $q'$, so the distance will typically have value $\infty$ if $A$ is an unbounded operator.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Could you provide a proof of the eigenvalue claim below?

Comment: Courant-Fischer Theorem.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo I still dont see "the numerator (resp., denominator) of your quotient is the largest (resp., smallest) eigenvalue of the operator $A$ on $H$ associated with $q′$"

Comment: Take e.g. $q'(f)=\|\nabla f\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}^2$ and $q(f)=\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$, $\Omega$ open and bounded. What you get is the $\sup$ and the $\inf$ of the Rayleigh quotient for the Laplacian with Dirichlet b.c., respectively. But I suppose this is not the setting the author of that paper had in mind.

Comment: (I must add I find it a bizarre notion of _distance_, since $d(q,q')=1$ if $q=q'$. But then I do not understand the difference between $q$ and $[q]$, so probably I am misunderstanding.)

Comment: There probably should be a log involved in the definition. Note also that if $q = \lambda q'$ the RHS is 1. This corresponds well with the definition that $[q]$ is the equivalent class of $q$ under the equivalent relation given by conformal scaling.

Comment: If you insert the missing $\log$ then for quadratic forms on a two dimensional vector space, the definition quoted is the same (up to constant factors) as the definition given in equation 1.2 of the second paper you linked to.

Comment: @WillieWong Why is numerator and denominator given as volume?

Comment: The area of an ellipse (working in two dimensions) is proportional to the products of the semi-principal axes. The semi-principal axes are the eigenvalues. Note that there's the requirement that $V_h$ and $V_{h'}$ are nested and touch along a circle. You achieve this by rescaling. In terms of what you have written this is requiring $\inf q'(x)/q(x) = 1$.